# tapPromise error when use gzip in webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to figure out how to properly compress my js file, the documentation of latter is a bit scarce.

My webpack configuration declares :

```
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
 plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: '[path].gz[query]', 
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            // test: /\.(js|css)$/,    
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
    ],
```

In the end the scripts are not correctly produced and compressed.I hit "npm run build"It give me the error

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\gg\node_modules\compression-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:283
      compilation.hooks.processAssets.tapPromise({
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapPromise' of undefined
```

How can I use webpack to use the compressed script.thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try Installing compatible **compression-webpack-plugin** package version.I got this issue fixed by downgrading my version from **10.0.0 to ^5.0.2** and it worked fine.

My webpack version is 4.42.0

Comment: This solved my issue, recommended to try is before moving to any other fix